# How does a host use its default gateway?

Tags: router, ip, default-gateway

Each host has its own default gateway and uses that to send packets outside of its network. But in each packet, there is only 1 header field for the destination IP address. So, how can that host send its packet to the default gateway and ask the gateway to send the packets outside?

Comment: You are forgetting that packets are encapsulated in frames for delivery on the LAN. There are many question with answers here if you search.

Comment: @RonMaupin so does it mean that the host must obtain the default gateway's MAC address by itself and then set that MAC address to the frame?

Comment: A gateway is just another host on a LAN, and the gateway layer-2 address (remember that not all layer-2 protocols use MAC addressing) is obtained the same way as any other  LAN layer-2 address. If the layer-2 protocol is something like ethernet that uses MAC addressing, then the source host uses ARP for IPv4 or NDP for IPv6.

Comment: @NguyễnNhân Yes.  The host uses ARP to do just that.